# Euro symbol are not displayed when pass from MSSQL to PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, character-encoding

I'm passing data from MSSQL server to PHP using Laravel. After, I have to pass data back to save it in a database.

Strings which contain **‎€** symbol, display **"?"** instead of this symbol.

`mb_detect_encoding($str)` for strings without **‎€** symbol returns `ASCII`

Otherwise `mb_detect_encoding($str)` returns **false**. Therefore, `json_encode($str)` doesn't work and returns **false** as well.

`mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');` returns a valid UTF-8 encoding.

So, I can run all the data which I'm getting from MSSQL trough this function to get `UTF-8` but how should I pass it back? In UTF-8 encoding?

MSSQL Collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, Laravel driver: `sqlsrv`

Comment: You should change the database connection character encoding to UTF-8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-send-and-retrieve-utf-8-data-using-built-in-utf-8-support?view=sql-server-2017 instead of trying to "fix" broken data after it's been received

Comment: @Joni I tried to put `'charset' => 'utf8'`,  `'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'` into my connection settings but it didn't help.

Comment: What is your column data type - `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: @Zhorov `nvarchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `PDO_sqlsrv` wasn't enabled.
Also, the problem is that by default `SqlServerConnector.php` using `pdo_dblib` driver instead of `pdo_sqlsrv` in Laravel 5.5. The priority was changed in the later versions.

Links helped me:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/118
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16986
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041658/sqlsrv-not-working-despite-having-a-proper-install